# IFeature.set_Shape The coordinates or measures are out of bounds

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-server, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, .net

I'm trying to add a point to my map, but something with the way I used shp2sde create caused me to have a incorrect spatial extent or something. So I'm getting "out of bounds" error.

How do I go about fixing this in ArcView 9.3.1? (I'll have to use command prompts probably or recreate).

My Map Server Info:

Intial Extent:

```
XMin: -197.114430117841
YMin: -95.6461199683022
XMax: 197.694572740662
YMax: 184.916970645712
Spatial Reference: 4326
```

Full Extent:

```
XMin: -198
YMin: -99
XMax: 198
YMax: 99
Spatial Reference: 4326
```

My Layer info:

Extent:

```
XMin: -180
YMin: -90
XMax: 180
YMax: 90
Spatial Reference: 4326
```

**Here's my log file from what I'm trying to INSERT into the feature layer:**

```
Check geometry point type=esriGeometryPoint
about to create feature
Create shape(X=38.9300285250005,Y=-74.9343213739996)
Com_point_spatialreference=GCS_WGS_1984
at ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature.set_Shape(IGeometry Shape)
 The coordinates or measures are out of bounds.
```

My sdelayer -o describe_long:

```
Spatial Column .......: SHAPE
Layer Id .............: 21
SRID .................: 5
Minimum Shape Id .....: 1
Offset ...............:
  falsex:          0.000000
  falsey:          0.000000
System Units .........:       1000.000000
Z Offset..............:          0.000000
Z Units ..............:          1.000000
Measure Offset .......: <None>
Measure Units ........: <None>
XY Cluster Tolerance .:          0.002
Spatial Index ........:
  parameter:    SPIDX_GRID,GRID0=1,FULL
  exist:        Yes
  array form:   1,0,0
Layer Envelope .......:
  minx:      -180.00000,        miny:       -90.00000
  maxx:       180.00000,        maxy:        90.00000
Entities .............: np
Layer Type ...........: SDE
Creation Date ........: 03/21/12 11:04:05
I/O Mode .............: LOAD
Autolocking ..........: Enabled
Precision.............: Basic
User Privileges ......: SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE
Coordinate System ....: GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1
984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292
5199433]]

Layer Configuration ..: DEFAULTS
```

Comment: Add custom points to the map changes the extent and I think sort of mitigates the problem. But how do I set it up so that any extent / x,y value is allowed based on GCS_WGS_1984 maps? I just want normal latitude longitude values without resorting to adding "border points" into the map to dynamically change the extent.

Comment: perhaps this is already mentioned in your question, but it is a little confusing to read - what told you that the initial extent had the values you wrote at the top of the question? None of these values are valid with the 4326 CRS. The longitude values extend beyond +/- 180 and latitude goes way beyond +/- 90. If these are the bounds of your source data it seems like the problem starts there

Comment: @tomfumb The layer info has the correct values that I manually entered in. The mapservice info, has these offsetted values 197 etc. It did it automatically. Otherwise I loaded a blank shape file with one layer, just attributes and no data. So how do you fix the extent??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be issue is with  tolerance: 0.002. It looks like its precision too rough, like taken from feature class in projected spatial reference. For geographic spatial reference it us usual like this: 0.000000008983001.

Comment: Well, you don't have the best answer, but thanks for trying. Good point about the resolution.